# Download Link for Custom File Type

Tags: iis7, webserver, download, filenames, iis6

I have a client that wants to make their products firmware files available for download on their website. The firmware files have a custom extension: .bi2. The client wants the files to be downloaded directly and not placed in a container (like a .zip file).

Is there an IIS setting that will instruct the browser to download the .bi2 file instead of trying to open it as a webpage?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for IIS to allow access to the file at all, it needs to be assigned a MIME-type. Use `application/octet-stream` and the browser will almost certainly treat it as a file it can't handle itself.

(You could also experiment with `application/x-whatever-you-want`)

Comment: +1 It might be useful to edit your question to add instructions on how to define a MIME type for a specific extension under IIS. (i.e. Quote the step-by-step instructions from [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965).)

Comment: @Nick, fair point, but first OP needs to edit the question to say which version of IIS, doesn't he?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Great point, I posted both because I don't know the answer. This particular website is hosted off-site and I don't know a whole lot about it. You're answer was great, and sufficient. I really just need to *sound* intelligent when I contact the hosting provider.